# What is a good HSM to test with?

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

What is a good (and cheap) HSM to test my PKCS11 applications with ? I am currently using SoftHSM but would like a physical HSM to test with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reality is that there are so many variants in PKCS#11 library behaviors working with HSM1 does not mean your application will work with HSM2, they just do so many oddball things you more-or-less need to test with each one.

With that said you can certainly get some confidence in your use of PKCS#11 by looking at other implementations.

Probably the cheapest way to get confidence your stuff will work with HSMs people actually use is using cloud offerings like those from Amazon (https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/).

Some inexpensive (but probably not representative) devices you can look at include:
- https://www.yubico.com/products/yubihsm/
- https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/
- https://shop.nitrokey.com/shop/product/nitrokey-hsm-7

If you have time you can usually pick up used nShield Edge devices for around $150 on ebay, these are fully representative (API wise) to their big brother HSMs. Be sure only to get ones that come with recent middleware you will have a hard time finding it.

Comment: After reading thru, I am thinking about getting the https://www.smartcard-hsm.com/  (usb model). It seems to be compatible with OpenSC and PKCS#11.  I think this would work fine linking to the opensc-pkcs11.so library from my application. Thoughts/suggestions ?

Comment: Its a fine choice.

Answer (score 0):

Although mostly U2F devices, but some have more advanced features: (Yubikey, Feitian, Fidesmo)?

https://github.com/hillbrad/U2FReviews